# Ho do I convert exclusion maven code to gradle

Tags: spring, maven, gradle

I am converting a maven project to gradle using converter. Here is maven code:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Here is what converter does:

```
testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:*"
```

I think it did everything well. But what about this?

```
<exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
```

Is it ok to omit it or smth in project would be changed?

And one more code:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
```

How can I convert it to gradle? Tag type jar confusing me. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent Gradle exclusion for your first snippet would be:

```
dependencies {
  testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
    exclude group: "org.junit.vintage", module: "junit-vintage-engine"
  }
}
```

Depending on how your tests are written, the exclusion may or may not impact you.

If you have JUnit 4 tests, then you want the JUnit Vintage module. So omit the exclusion.

However if you only have JUnit 5 tests, then you probably do not want any of the JUnit 4 (JUnit Vintage) stuff.

---

Aside: [Spring Boot 2.2.x includes both JUnit 4 and 5](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#junit-5). I believe starting in 2.3.x, the Spring Boot team started excluding JUnit 4 as shown above and eventually [removed JUnit 4 in 2.4.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.4-Release-Notes#junit-5s-vintage-engine-removed-from-spring-boot-starter-test)